# Strange ip command output

Tags: linux, networking, ip, network-interface

When I call `ip addr show` I get output with all interfaces and their IP addresses (look at `eth7`):

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:42:e9:3d:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.11.98.248/16 brd 172.11.255.255 scope global eth1
3: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc cbq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:42:c6:d0:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.28.98.242/19 brd 10.28.127.255 scope global eth2
4: eth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:42:56:14:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.28.98.249/24 scope global eth4
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:42:03:06:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.28.98.230/19 brd 10.28.127.255 scope global eth3
6: eth7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:42:4d:cb:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.28.98.231/24 scope global eth7
    inet 192.168.13.0/18 scope global eth7
7: eth5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:42:81:0a:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: eth6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:42:5c:12:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/ether b2:c1:df:b1:29:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.47.130.2/24 brd 10.47.130.255 scope global br0
10: br1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/ether 52:b4:3a:90:f2:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/void
```

But when I call the same command `ip addr show up`, but for only up-ed interfaces, I get strange results:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:42:e9:3d:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.11.98.248/16 brd 172.11.255.255 scope global eth1
3: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc cbq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:42:c6:d0:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.28.98.242/19 brd 10.28.127.255 scope global eth2
4: eth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:42:56:14:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.28.98.249/24 scope global eth4
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:42:03:06:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.28.98.230/19 brd 10.28.127.255 scope global eth3
    inet 10.28.98.231/24 scope global eth7
    inet 192.168.13.0/18 scope global eth7
9: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/ether b2:c1:df:b1:29:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.47.130.2/24 brd 10.47.130.255 scope global br0
10: br1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/ether 52:b4:3a:90:f2:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/void
```

I'm expecting that down interfaces will just dissapear from output. But, somehow strange for me, I see that not only they dissapear, but also IP addresses `192.168.13.0/18`, `10.28.98.231/24` previously assigned to `eth7` is currently assigned to `eth3`.

*Is this normal behaviour and why this happen? And why these IP addresses were assigned to `eth3` interfaces and not to others?*

Comment: Sounds like a bug ip `ip`!!! It's skipping the header information for interfaces that are down but still printing the associated IP addresses, making them look like they're attached to a different interface.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem here, by the way, with `ip` version 3.12.0.

Comment: Still wrong in 3.16.0

Comment: I've reported this as a bug in Debian, #776040

Comment: Oh no, It's not a bug, `ip a` is such as `ip addr show` such as `ifconfig -a`, They show all of  ethernet even down ethernet, But when you use `ip addr show up` or  `ifconfig ` you can only watch up eth.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh, read the original post. Problem that IP assigned to down interface appears on another up-ed interface.

Comment: @Celada Make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's a bug.](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=776040) There's a patch already, so you can expect it to be fixed in the next release. Thanks to [wurtel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/83831/wurtel) for reporting it.